# Why is my $_POST ['username'] not refreshing everytime on one of my sessions?

Tags: php, html, sql, session, post

I have two sessions here and use the $POST ['username'] in both related queries, but on the $_SESSION['address'] it still is taking my old $POST ['username'] so therefore it is not refreshed.

```
<?php

include_once'config/connect.php'; //database connection

if($_POST['submit']) {

    $retrieve = mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM iangadot_user
                             WHERE username='".$_POST['username']."' AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."' ");
    $address = mysql_query("SELECT location FROM venue
                            WHERE vid in (select vid from  user_venue where id in (select id from iangadot_user where username='".$_POST['username']."' )) ");
    if(mysql_num_rows($retrieve)) {

        //redirect to your client page...
        //SET YOUR session
        $_SESSION['username_profile'] = $_POST['username'];
        header("Location: clientpag.php");


    } else {
        echo "<script language=javascript>alert('Wrong username or password')</script>";
        //header("Location: ./?errorlogged=err");


    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($address)) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($address);
        $_SESSION['address'] = $row['location'];

        header("Location: clientpag.php");

    }

}


?>
```

Here is my Html code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 id = "title" name= venue> Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username_profile'] ?> </h1>

<input class = "field" placeholder= "<?php echo $_SESSION['address'] ?>" type="text" >
<input class = "button" type = "submit" Value = "Save"><br>
 ......... code continued......
```

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Did you have session_start();  in your first file?

Comment: no not on my php file @AwladLiton

Comment: Add session_start(); in the top in your php file. It should work after that if it executes $_SESSION['address'] = $row['location']; line correctly

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but it would seem that your second query does not return any rows and therefore the session variable is not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php file add session start:

```
<?php

include_once'config/connect.php'; //database connection
session_start();
```

if it executes

`$_SESSION['address'] = $row['location'];`
line correctly then you will have `$_SESSION['address']` it in your next page.

**REMEMBER:**

You need start session by session_start() in every files where you want to use session.

See details:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 4):

You need to start the session in every file where you set or use `$_SESSION`
at the beginning of the script: `session_start();`

Comment: I just tried this but that didnt fix the problem. you see my first session is renewed every time but it is the second one that doesnt.

Comment: what do you mean by first and second session??

Comment: `$_SESSION['username_profile'] = $_POST['username'];
header("Location: clientpag.php");`: here you go to another page, so the rest of the code is not executed?